# Kubernetes: Access to ALSA audio device

Tags: kubernetes, alsa

I'd like to record radio using [Sonifex audio capturing cards](https://www.sonifex.co.uk/de/radiocards/pc-fm6-32.shtml) hardware using ffmpeg via its ALSA driver from a container running on Kubernetes. Is it possible, and how do I configure it?

My Kubernetes cluster is based on k3s.

Thanks

Comment: How should your application behave if it gets rescheduled on a different node in the cluster?  Are you guaranteed that every node will have identical specialized hardware like this?  (I'd probably run this application directly on the host, not in a container and not under a cluster manager.)

Comment: just curious what's your setup ( in other words why do you need to run a recording software from a container) ?

Comment: I have several identical machines with such cards and when the software starts up, it instructs the card to tune into the desired frequency and recording starts. I want to record in a container because of all the benefits of it, easy management of a cluster, monitoring, alerts, health checks, etc.

Comment: I've searched on this topic, but can't find any useful info. Have you managed to solve the problem?